# Are methods with covariant arguments allowed or prohibited in Python?

Tags: python, generics, covariance, mypy

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T_co = TypeVar('T_co', covariant=True)

class CovariantClass(Generic[T_co]):
    def get_t(self, t: T_co) -> T_co:  # <--- Mypy: cannot use a covariant type variable as a parameter
        return t
```

see [closed mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7049)

My reading of the PEPs [484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) and [483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance) is that covariant **functions** are prohibited but covariant methods are allowed and mypy is "wrong" to flag it. That's to say that if the class is **declared** by the author as covariant then it is their responsibility to ensure that any covariant method in the class is well-behaved (e.g. by not appending to collection of covariant items).

from PEP 484:

> Consider a class Employee with a subclass Manager. Now suppose we have a function with an argument annotated with List[Employee]. Should we be allowed to call this function with a variable of type List[Manager] as its argument? Many people would answer "yes, of course" without even considering the consequences. But unless we know more about the function, a type checker should reject such a call: the function might append an Employee instance to the list, which would violate the variable's type in the caller.
>
> It turns out such an argument acts contravariantly, whereas the intuitive answer (which is correct in case the function doesn't mutate its argument!) requires the argument to act covariantly.
>
> ....
>
> Covariance or contravariance is not a property of a type variable, but a property of a generic class defined using this variable. Variance is only applicable to generic types; generic functions do not have this property. The latter should be defined using only type variables without covariant or contravariant keyword arguments.

It then gives an example of a prohibited function with a covariant argument.

Also from PEP 483 as evidence against the argument put forward in the closed mypy issue that it is prohibited to keep python type-safe (emphasis as in the PEP):

> It is possible to **declare** the variance for user defined generic types

PEP 484 contains a class with a covariant argument in the `__init__` but there is no example I could find in the PEPs of a covariant argument in a method showing it to be explicitly either allowed or prohibited.

```
T_co = TypeVar('T_co', covariant=True)
class ImmutableList(Generic[T_co]):
    def __init__(self, items: Iterable[T_co]) -> None: ...
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T_co]: ...
    ...
```

EDIT 1: simple example of where this could be useful as requested in the comments. An extra method in the above class from the PEP:

```
    def is_member(self, item: T_co) -> bool:
        return item in self._items
```

EDIT 2: another example in case the first one seems academic

```
    def k_nearest_neighbours(self, target_item: T_co, k: int) -> list[T_co]:
        nearest: list[T_co] = []
        distances: list[float] = [item.distance_metric(target_item)
                                  for item in self._items]
        ...
        return nearest
```

Comment: btw it doesn't apply to `__init__` because that's not really a method on instances

Comment: i'd also be interested to see an example of where it is safe and necessary to use a covariant argument. In your example, a completely unrelated invariant type variable would do

Comment: @joel example added in edit above. ```mgrs.is_member(my_employee)``` will give a type error on my_employee (as desired), but ```dump_employees(mgrs)``` still will not since covariant (see PEP 484 example linked above for the full code).

Comment: fwiw i do recall seeing somewhere a long and involved argument about the case of set membership in this context. I don't recall there being a conclusion. I think the discussion was whether in that case it makes sense to check if a `str` is a member of a `set[int]`

Comment: i have to be honest, I've got too much on atm to focus on this. I hope you find a satisfying conclusion

Comment: @joel No problem, thanks anyway.